# What does adukin (אדוקין) mean?

Tags: hebrew, translation, rashi, maseches-gitin

Rashi, [in Mesechta Gitin on דף טז עמוד א](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2480&size=1) says שנים אדוקין. What does adukin (אדוקין) mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yeshiva I learned that the word Adukin means connected

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the word "Haduk-tight".

Answer (score 8):

[Prof Marcus Jastrow](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38236&st=&pgnum=33) translates as "Take hold of; cling; joined; stick to."